# math domain error when normalizing vectors

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I'm following a class on vectors and I tried to implement the vectors operations in Python which I'm kind of learning in the process. I'm getting a math domain error when normalizing the vectors. Any idea why ?

The error I'm getting is :

Line 67, in angle_with
    raise(e)
ValueError: math domain error

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 30

class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple([Decimal(x) for x in coordinates])
            self.dim ension = len(coordinates)

        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('The coordinates must be nonempty')

        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')


def __str__(self):
    return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)

def plus(self, v):
    new_coordinates = [x+y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
    return Vector(new_coordinates)

def minus(self, v):
    new_coordinates = [x-y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)]
    return Vector(new_coordinates)

def times_scalar(self, c):
    new_coordinates = [Decimal(c)*x for x in self.coordinates]
    return Vector(new_coordinates)

def magnitude(self):
    coordinates_squared = [x**2 for x in self.coordinates]
    return Decimal(math.sqrt(sum(coordinates_squared)))

def normalized(self):
    try:
        magnitude = self.magnitude()
        return self.times_scalar(Decimal('1.0')/magnitude)

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise Exception('Cannot normalize the zero vector')

def dot_product(self, v):
    return sum([x*y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)])

def angle_with(self, v, in_degrees=False):
    try:
        u1 = self.normalized()
        u2 = v.normalized()
        angle_in_radians = math.acos(u1.dot_product(u2))

        if in_degrees:
            degrees_per_radian = 180 / math.pi
            return angle_in_radians * degrees_per_radian
        else:
            return angle_in_radians

    except Exception as e:
        if str(e) == 'Cannot normalize the zero vector':
            raise Exception('Cannot compute an angle with the zero vector')
        else:
            raise(e)

a = Vector(['-7.579', '-7.88'])
b = Vector(['22.737', '23.64'])
print a.is_parallel_to(b)
print a.is_orthogonal(b)
```

Comment: Are these coming from a class definition? `self` doesn't make sense in your question

Comment: Your problem seems to be that your `dot_product` function is returning a number less than -1 in some cases (presumably due to finite floating point precision). `math.acos` treats this input as a domain error.

Comment: There are two places where math domain error can occur, either when computing `math.sqrt` of negative number, or `math.acos` of number outside of range [-1, 1]. Please, double check arguments to these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Łukasz Rogalski pointed out that acos will cause this error if the dot product of u1 and u2 is outside [-1, 1]. 
If you normalize vectors a and b and check the dot product with a precision of 30 like you have, you will see the problem.

Change your precision to 10 or so to take care of this error.